# How to jump to Pascal notation on alt arrow key press in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How to jump to Pascal notation on alt arrow key press in IntelliJ IDEA? When using IntelliJ and there is the word `oneTwoThree`, If you press the right arrow key when placing the cursor in front of `o`, I want to position the cursor at `T` rather than at `e`.

I'm wondering how can I move to Pascal notation.

Answer (score 0):

> "Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Smart Keys --> Use "CamelHumps" words"

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000132804-Navigating-through-camelCasedWords-with-the-Ctrl-key